# How to find Stored Procedures With Recompile?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2016, dmv, metadata

In my databases I have some [Stored procedure with recompile](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/108669/22336)

The way I find them is:

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(ID)AS SP_NAME,* 
FROM SYSCOMMENTS
WHERE TEXT LIKE '%WITH RECOMPILE%'
```

when I look at:

```
select * from sys.procedures
```

I find no indication of [recompiles](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/75843/22336).

Is there a better or more elegant way to find the [with recompile](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/174908/22336) stored procedures?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Per database, you can do this:

```
SELECT          DISTINCT
                DB_NAME() AS DBName, 
                SO.name AS SPName, 
                SM.is_recompiled, 
                ISR.SPECIFIC_SCHEMA
FROM            sys.sql_modules AS SM
LEFT OUTER JOIN master.sys.databases AS sDB
    ON SM.object_id = DB_ID()
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.sysobjects AS SO
    ON  SM.object_id = SO.id
    AND SO.type = 'P'
LEFT OUTER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES AS ISR
    ON  ISR.ROUTINE_NAME = SO.name
    AND ISR.SPECIFIC_CATALOG = DB_NAME()
WHERE           SM.is_recompiled = 1;
```

Comment: Hey doesn't the Brent Ozar's & Team's  sp_blitz stored procedure find that for you when you run it ?

Comment: @Shanky sure, if you're into that sort of thing ;)